# Extend stay in Singapore during transit

Tags: luggage, layovers, singapore, singapore-airlines

I have a trip from Surabaya (Indonesia) to Thailand with Singapore Airlines. The flight will be SUB-SIN-BKK and BKK-SIN-SUB. I'll have a 17-hour layover on the way out, and a 7-hour layover on the way back.

Can I get my check-in baggage during the layover in Changi? And is it okay if I want to extend my stay in Singapore before going back to Indonesia? Do I have to buy another SIN-SUB ticket?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your citizenship? Do you need a visa to enter Singapore?

Comment: I’m an Indonesian so i guess I don’t need visa to enter Singapore

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to check in your luggage only up to Singapore on the way back. And since I assume you're Indonesian, you don't need a visa for Singapore. So picking up your luggage and going out wouldn't be an issue.

However, depending on the pricing tier of your ticket you might be able to change it -- or not. And even if you can change the last leg, Singapore - Surabaya, you'll probably have to pay something. But it will probably be cheaper than buying a new ticket.

If you don't get on the last leg without talking with the airline (and if it's a cheap ticket even if you do), the ticket will be cancelled and you'll need to buy a new ticket.

Comment: Is it permitted to check in my luggage up to Singapore? All of my flights are using Singapore Airlines. As I know there is a check-in through facility at Changi.

Comment: I suppose you didn't get the main point of my answer: speak with the airline.